# Find the majority in dataframe using pandas.DataFrame.mode and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

how to get a new column for the majority of each group?

sample dataframe

```
    who        state
0   peopleA     CA
1   peopleA     CA
2   peopleA     CA
3   peopleA     NJ
4   peopleB     FL
5   peopleB     FL
6   peopleB     CA
```

this's not the right way to code

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('who').mode()
```

my expected output

```
    who        new_column
0   peopleA      CA
1   peopleB      FL
```

Bonus question:
Is there a way to set a threshold to control if the count greater than 70%, then consider as majority, if less than 70%, return null

Comment: Is this what you want?:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Slice on the 'who' and count the 'State'?

Comment: @JeffEllen not exactlly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by column `who`, then apply `mode` function on the df groupby object and then call `reset_index` and pass param `drop=True` so that the multi-index is not added back as a column

```
>>> df
       who state
0  peopleA    CA
1  peopleA    CA
2  peopleA    CA
3  peopleA    NJ
4  peopleB    FL
5  peopleB    FL
6  peopleB    CA
>>> 
>>> df.groupby('who').apply(pd.DataFrame.mode).reset_index(drop=True)
       who state
0  peopleA    CA
1  peopleB    FL
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a threshold to control if the count greater than 70%, then consider as majority, if less than 70%, return null?

Comment: how to specify the column's name for mode function if I have more that two columns?

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.groupby` does not have `mode()`. A workaround is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13809). Basically after grouping, you can use `.apply()` to the grouper and find mode specific to that group.

```
df.groupby('who').state.apply(lambda x: x.mode()).reset_index(0)
```

Output:

```
      who   state
0   peopleA CA
0   peopleB FL
```

Comment: it works, but the index number become 0 and 0